# Access denied reading java.util.Permissions

Tags: websphere, eclipselink, java-7

we are using websphere 17 for a web application based on eclipse-link as persistence layer. Application works fine but after a while (during user activity) we got this kind of error that forces us to restart of server.

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.sqlTranslationProfile" "read")
Error Code: 0
```

what is the meaning of this error ?

From what I understood this error happens because there is no reading access to that property. But this could be due to security manager. Problem is I would expect any security manager set by websphere and for sure we are not creating any custom security manager. Security manager should not exist at all in our application. So, who is setting it ? Or am I missing something ?

Following is the full stacktrace:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.sqlTranslationProfile" "read")
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.sqlTranslationProfile" "read")
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:822)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.sqlTranslationProfile" "read")
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:1576)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:1434)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:309)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:143)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.sqlTranslationProfile" "read")
    at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermissionHelper(AccessController.java:237)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:373)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:562)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1307)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedPhysicalConnection$1.run(GeneratedPhysicalConnection.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedPhysicalConnection.getSystemProperty(GeneratedPhysicalConnection.java:82)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedPhysicalConnection.getSystemPropertySqlTranslationProfile(GeneratedPhysicalConnection.java:46)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:555)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:164)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper$1.run(DatabaseHelper.java:949)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper.getPooledConnection(DatabaseHelper.java:958)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:810)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:1354)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

The `websphere.java.security` property in bootstrap.properties controls whether Java 2 Security is enabled in Liberty.

When running with Java 2 Security enabled, here is an example server config snippet (for server.xml file) of how to grant permission for the oracle JDBC driver to read System properties that begin with "oracle.jdbc.",

```
<javaPermission codebase="C:/drivers/oracle/ojdbc7.jar" className="java.util.PropertyPermission" actions="read" name="oracle.jdbc.*"/>
```